# How to convert date time format of this 17:57.4 to this format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f' in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format

I am extracting column2 which has Date-Time from .csv file,  in csv file i can see like this format of date time (17:57.4),but Whenever i use below code to convert its format from (17:57.4) to `format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'`

i am getting only NAN values at output.

csv file datetime column

```
f['column2']

17:57.4
17:57.4
17:57.4
17:57.4
17:57.4
17:57.4
17:57.4
17:57.4
17:57.4
```

I used this code

```
df['column2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column2'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Comment: Are you sure 17:57.4 contains a year, month and day? Also, make sure to put your code between ``.